# Does ORDER BY only work with columns?

Tags: sql

Why does `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND()` Work?  I thought `ORDER BY` only works for columns.

So what exactly does it mean to `ORDER BY RAND()` or `ORDER BY SUM()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` will work with any value you can put in your results (but doesn't have to be one of the values in the results).  This can be a column in any of the source tables or calculated using a function.  For example, you could use `ORDER UPPER(name)` for a case-insensitive sort.

If you `ORDER BY RAND()` you're ordering by a random number generated for each row in the results, i.e. returning the rows in a random order.  If you're ordering by `SUM()` you've probably got a `GROUP BY` in there too so you could order customers by total calculated invoice total for example.

Ideally you want to use a column from an index as this will be much faster.

Answer (score 10):

**You can order by nearly everything**, functions (*like RAND())*, aggregations (*like SUM()*) and so on.

For example, the [MySQL-Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) states as Syntax:

```
 [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
```

Or the [Postgresql Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-select.html) is even more explicit:

> The optional **ORDER BY** clause has this general form:
>
> `ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC | USING operator ] [, ...]`
>
> expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list item), **or it can be an arbitrary expression** formed from input-column values.

For your second question:

- `ORDER BY RAND()` or `ORDER BY RANDOM()` does what it states: Your rows are shuffeled and you get them in a random order. So if you do a `SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` you select a (=one) random row out of your table.
- `ORDER BY SUM(Column)` only makes sense in combination with a `GROUP BY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the implementation.The statement you mentioned is not SQL92-compatible but it may be accepted by an implementation.

Answer (score -4):

Well, to put it short: You thought wrong.

Comment: Whenever an answer this short has been posted, I saw them downvoted.